error in grub after mint 22 upgrade
I have 2 ssd ( one for Windows 10 and the other for linux mint ) .
i used mint upgrade to update from 21.3 to 22 , the upgrade is successful but when booting up and choosing either mint 22 or windows 10 it shows the following error :

In this error I press enter then try to choose os again which enter successfully to the os meaning that the error shows once everytime I turn on pc
tried sudo update-grub with no luck
any help is appreciated .

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

If you can't boot how exactly have you run sudo update-grub?

In this error I press enter then try to choose os again which enter successfully to the os meaning that the error shows once everytime I turn on pc

If so that should be [edit]ed in the question. While at that you may also remove the mention to "2 SSDs" (irrelevant), correct the capitalization (as in "I", at the beginning of every sentence and in names (Windows, Linux Mint, etc.), code fence any commands, ...
